# Session lock in Symfony prevent loading other page

Tags: php, symfony, session, locking, session-cookies

I'm currently building a very basic application with Symfony 5.
But I have a problem.

When I run a task that lasts a certain time, I can't load a secondary page until the task is finished.

More in detail, I have a button on my page named "start process" which makes a call to a controller that will execute a symfony command (which itself executes a python script).

Le code JS rien de plus basique jusque ici

```
        const startProcessBtn = document.querySelector('#startProcessBtn');

        startProcessBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>
        {
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/startProcess').then(response =>
            {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
```

Here my controller function

```
    /**
     * @Route("/startProcess", name="startProcess")
     * @param HubInterface $hub
     *
     * @throws \JsonException
     */
    public function startProcess(KernelInterface $kernel, Request $request)
    {
            $request->getSession()->start();
            $request->getSession()->save();
            $application = new Application($kernel);
            $application->setAutoExit(false);

            $queue    = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Entity::class)->getNotProccesed();
            $progress = 0;
            $total    = count($queue);

            foreach ($queue as $queueItem)
            {
                $progress++;
                $update = new Update('http://localhost:8000/process', json_encode(['status' => 'info', 'title' => 'Start process'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
                $this->hub->publish($update);
                $input = new ArrayInput([
                                            'command'         => 'command:start',
                                        ]);
                $application->run($input);
                $update = new Update('http://localhost:8000/process', json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'title' => 'Finish process'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
                $this->hub->publish($update);
                $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Entity::class)->setIsProccessedById($queueItem->getId());
            }


        return new Response('ok');
    }
```

I already had a problem of the kind which blocked the execution of a script, because a script was already in execution. This was due to the Session that had to be closed to allow another script to read it. At that time I had used session_write_close() and my problem was solved, but here I am on Symfony, but even using the session and closing it does not work.

The problem persists.

My task currently lasts ~2 minutes which means that during this time I can't do anything on the application simultaneously and these tasks could be increased to 10 minutes or more.

If someone could help me, thank you very much!
Have a nice day/evening :-D

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue. From the sound of things, you may have other background tasks running that is causing the issue, since `session_write_close()` is called with `Session::save();` and does resolve the well-known session lock problem. unless you are not using the `NativeSessionStorage`. In general for long running tasks you should move them to a queueing system like [Messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) or a cron job, which will run the task(s) outside of the webserver.

Comment: As I can see you send the request to 'http://localhost:8000/'. What web server do you use? My assumption is that you use symfony dev web server, which uses php-fpm server under the hood. Here https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php you can see "The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.". My suggestion: use another web server like nginx, apache, etc.

Comment: @lis-dev Yes indeed you are totally right, I use the symfony server.
I put the project under docker so with nginx, but the problem persists. I don't know much about nginx, I have several possible versions (nginx, nginx-alpine, nginx-perl, nginx-alpine-perl). A configuration? Thanks